# Reopen Swift 2.0 migration tool in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, swift

I just opened a Swift project on the new Xcode 7.

I didn't really look on what button I clicked and closed the migration tools without migrating anything.

Any idea how I could reopen it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To begin migration to swift 2.0 latest syntax, open your Xcode project with xcode7, Click *Edit > Convert*. See this link:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/

[image]